# How to stop the execution of Java program from Command line?

Tags: java, interrupt

My main field is .Net but recently I have got something to do with Java. I have to create a shell utility in Java that could run in background reading few database records after specified duration and do further processing. It's a kind of scheduler. Now I have few concerns:

How to make this work as a service. I want to execute it through a shell script and the utility should start running. Off course the control should get back to the calling script.

Secondly, eventually i may want to stop this process from running. How to achieve this?

I understand these are basic question but I really have no idea where to begin and what options are best for me.

Any help / advise please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the running the program using a scheduler or a service.  However, if you wish to use a bat file and do this programmatically, I have outlined a possible approach below:

In your Java program, you can get the PID programmatically, and then write it to a file:

```
public static void writePID(String fileLocation) throws IOException
{
    // Use the engine management bean in java to find out the pid
    // and to write to a file
    if (fileLocation.length() == 0)
    {
        fileLocation = DEFAULT_PID_FILE;
    }       
    String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    if (pid.indexOf("@") != -1) 
    {
        pid = pid.substring(0, pid.indexOf("@"));
    }                                               
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileLocation));
    writer.write(pid);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();                     
}
```

You can then write a stop .bat file that will kill the running program in windows.  You could do something like:

```
setlocal
IF EXIST app.pid FOR /F %%i in ('type app.pid') do TASKKILL /F /PID %%i   
IF EXIST app.pid DEL app.pid
endlocal
```

Of course, app.pid is the file written by the Java method above.

I am not sure how you would be able to write a script that launches a java program, and reverts control on termination.  I would be interested to see if anybody has a solution for that.

Comment: Is that means that I may have to write another java application that will read that file and kill the running process?

Comment: No, the .bat file is the bit that is killing your process. It is a bit of VBScript that is killing the running app. 

IF EXIST app.pid FOR /F %%i in ('type app.pid') do TASKKILL /F /PID %%i   

If you are running this on *nix, you could write a shell script that does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are playing your java program with a Linux/Unix box.
To run your application as a daemon, you can try

```
nohup java YourJavaClass &
```

To stop your application, you can either:

```
kill [psIdofYourApplication]
```

or

```
fg [your application job Id]
Ctrl-C
```

If you want to do some postprocessing after the application receiving 'kill/stop' signal. check out [addShutdownHook(Thread hook)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Or sun.misc.SignalHandler

Answer (score 1):

```
ps ux
```

see `pid`

```
kill pid
```

Or you'd better provide a stopping script that signals the application, which does `System.exit(0)`

Comment: as long as he isn't doing something like database transactions, killing the pid is fine. If he has database transactions, may need to do it a little more fancily.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the platform.  If on Windows you should look into integrating with the Service Control to create a Windows service.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service.  Once you've implemented the service hooks, it is possible to start and stop the service through the service control GUI or using `net stop MyService` syntax from the command line.

Comment: I want to do this on Unix platform. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want something like this:

```
if ( System.in.avaliable() > 0 ) {
  in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in );
  String InLine = in.readLine();
  ...
}
```

Am I right?